# Building minizip for 32-bit linux

Tags: c, zlib, minizip

I have an application that uses minizip for manipulating .zip files. It currently uses a very old version of minizip (pre-64bit port) and I am upleveling to the latest version (as shipped with zlib 1.2.13).

One of my build targets is 32-bit linux using a 32-bit I/O model. I am having trouble integrating the new minizip because it is forcing a 64-bit I/O model via the series of #defines at the top of ioapi.h:

```
  // Linux needs this to support file operation on files larger then 4+GB
  // But might need better if/def to select just the platforms that needs them.

        #ifndef __USE_FILE_OFFSET64
                #define __USE_FILE_OFFSET64
        #endif
        #ifndef __USE_LARGEFILE64
                #define __USE_LARGEFILE64
        #endif
        #ifndef _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
                #define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
        #endif
        #ifndef _FILE_OFFSET_BIT
                #define _FILE_OFFSET_BIT 64
        #endif
```

The consequence of this code is that any of my modules that #include "zip.h" will build with the 64-bit data structures and any other modules in my build tree will use 32-bit data structures.

Here is a test program that shows the issue. We compile one .c file that #includes "zip.h" and another .c file that does not. We compare the size of the `rlim_t` type across the two files.

```
// main.c

#include "zip.h"
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

extern void sizetest(size_t x);

int main(void)
{
   sizetest(sizeof(rlim_t));

   return 0;
}
```

```
// sizetest.c

#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

void sizetest(size_t x)
{
   assert(sizeof(rlim_t) == x);
}
```

Compile with -m64 and it works.

```
$ gcc -m64 main.c sizetest.c -o sizetest -I <path to zlib>/contrib/minizip
$ ./sizetest
```

Compile with -m32 and it asserts.

```
$ gcc -m32 main.c sizetest.c -o sizetest -I <path to zlib>/contrib/minizip
$ ./sizetest                                                                               
sizetest: sizetest.c:9: sizetest: Assertion `sizeof(rlim_t) == x' failed.
Abort(coredump)
```

Has anyone else dealt with this? I understand that I can hack the minizip code to make it work like I want but I try to avoid making custom changes to 3rd party code in my build tree.

Comment: If this is a bug you could report it and get it fixed at the source.

Comment: Which one of all the minizip forks are you using?

Comment: 32-bit Linux has supported 64-bit file sizes for a long time (as has windows for that matter). I would argue that the proper fix is to change your code to deal with the fact that file sizes are not limited to machine word-size.

Comment: It seems like a type size mismatch between rlim_t and size_t types, which are basically unsigned integers.
I guess there is a dependency between rlim_t  and __USE_FILE_OFFSET64 on 32 bit platform which forces rlim_t  64 bit unsigned integer. However, on 32 bit platform size_t seems to be 32 bit unsigned long.  In order to be sure check rlim_t type definition at sys/resource.h and size_t  (or __SIZE_TYPE__ ?) in stddef.h.